# Multiple values in one column value print in unix output

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
Ravi : Siva : Venki 
Siva : venki : Venkata krishna 
Reddy 
date : Number : test
```

2nd row 3rd column values have multiple lines 
output should be like below for 3rd columns values 
Output

```
Venki 
Venkata krishna  Reddy 
test
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Use `{}` in the editor to mark the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
> cat broken_3rd_col.txt
Ravi : Siva : Venki 
Siva : venki : Venkata krishna 
Reddy 
date : Number : test 
> awk -F":" ' { if(NF==1) { prev=prev$1; next } if( prev !~/^$/ && NR>1 ) { print prev ;} prev=$0 } END { print prev }' broken_3rd_col.txt
Ravi : Siva : Venki 
Siva : venki : Venkata krishna Reddy 
date : Number : test 
> 
> awk -F":" ' { if(NF==1) { prev=prev$1; next } if( prev !~/^$/ && NR>1 ) { print prev ;} prev=$0 } END { print prev }' broken_3rd_col.txt | awk -F":" ' { print $3 } ' 
 Venki 
 Venkata krishna Reddy 
 test 
>
```

Update1:

Based on new input:

```
$ cat date_pattern.txt
2018-11-18 03:05:17 : INFO : (571 | WRITER_1__1) : node02_p : WRT_8167 : Start loading table [DUAL] at: Sun Nov 18 03:05:16 2018
2018-11-18 03:05:17 : INFO : (571 | WRITER_1_1) : node02_p : WRT_8168 : End loading table [DUAL] at: Sun Nov 18 03:05:16 2018
2018-11-18 03:05:17 : INFO : (571 | WRITER_1*_1) : node02_p : WRT_8035 : Load complete time: Sun Nov 18 03:05:16 2018

LOAD SUMMARY
============

WRT_8036 Target: DUAL (Instance Name: [DUAL1])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target

2018-11-18 03:05:17 : INFO : (571 | WRITER_1_*_1) : node02_p : WRT_8168 : End loading table [DUAL] at: Sun Nov 18 03:05:16 2018

$ awk -F" " ' { if($0!~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}/) { prev=prev$0; next } if( prev !~/^$/ && NR>1 ) { print prev ;} prev=$0 } END { print prev }' date_pattern.txt  | perl -ne
 ' { if( /(.+?) WRT(.+?):(.+)/ and $x=$3 ) { print "$x\n" } } '  > res4.txt

$
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help … but my 3rd column values like below ..                              Load complete time: Sun Nov 18 03:05:16 2018

LOAD SUMMARY
============

WRT_8036 Target: DUAL (Instance Name: [DUAL1])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target

Comment: can you update it in the question.. the comment is not formatting correctly

Comment: in that case, splitting on : will not work, we have to check on 1st column with time stamp pattern and whatever comes in between should be rolled up to single row. please post it as a new question and share the link here..

Comment: thanks for the solution , can you please explin the code once , It could be very helpful to me ….

Comment: it is similar to the previous one.. only the perl part would be somewhat difficult to understand...